# Can't change color of current-cat in Wordpress Woocommerce Categories

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

Looking to change the color of the "children" in the current category when clicked on.

http://www.montagewestport.com

For example, in the furniture page, in the left sidebar, if you click a category and go to the page, I'm trying to make that page's newly visible "subcategories" display a different color.

I think it has something to do with the current-cat class or the children class, but I can't get it to work.

Does anybody have experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have seen on your website you have multiple navigation levels and I didn't know which level, so I'll give you the two examples.

If you mean the first level you can add following to your css file:

```
.children li {
    background-color: beige;
}
```

If you mean the level underneath the children, do following:

```
.children li ul li {
    background-color: beige;
}
```

I you would like to change the text color do like this:

first level

```
.widget .children li a {
    color: #1fb4b9;
}
```

second level

```
.widget .children li ul li a {
    color: #1fb4b9;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works.  Is there a reason why only background-color works?  Ideally I would just like to change the color of the text with "color:#1fb4b9;" but that isn't changing.

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question. For giving `background-color` you have to style the `<li>` element, for the text itself you must style the `<a>` element with `color` attribute.

Comment: Please also note that first level is the parent so second level will inherit from there. So make sure to declare both levels if you want for each different colors.